# Consistent LM Model and then Predict - Loop with data being subsetting directly in lm and Predict function

Tags: r, loops, lm, predict

I am hoping there is an semi-simple way to make this happen.

For sake of this, I build a sample data set (CountryCode is a proxy for country name - I just wanted to prove a sample data set to help understand the ask);

````
```
set.seed(20)
House <- data.frame(Price = sample(350000:625000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
          LotSize = sample(5000:45000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
          SqFt = sample(18000:32000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
          Bedroom = sample(3:5, 200, replace=TRUE), 
          HomeAge = rnorm(200, mean=15, sd=5), 
          CountryCode = sample(300:305, 200, replace=TRUE))
```
````

I have a linear model similar to the below;

```
model<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, data=House[House$CountryCode==300,])
```

If I wanted to run this same model, however in a loop by each country code (so the x would change based upon the country code), could this be done?

Because of fx rates, the value of HomePrice is not a typical continuous factor; a price of 300,000 in the US (USD) is different than a price of 300,000 in France (EUR). And even 300,000 EUR would be different within Europe. However, if the model only considered in the model build same country, price would have a continuous aspect to it.

Basically, a loop where `i=CountryCode` and the loop would do the `model_i<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, data=House[House$CountryCode==i,])` and it runs based upon the subset of i (or each CountryCode) and saves it as `model_i(each Country)`

The end result I would ideally like to see is;

````
```
model_300<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, 
    data=House[House$CountryCode==300,])

model_301<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, 
    data=House[House$CountryCode==301,])

model_302<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, 
    data=House[House$CountryCode==302,])
```
````

Could a similar loop then be used to do a predict?

`````
```
predict_i<-predict(model_i,newdata=(House[House$CountryCode==i,]), 
    interval="confidence", level=.70)
````
`````

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT -
So I am getting closer (I think), however would love some help to get this across the finish line;

```
set.seed(20)
House <- data.frame(Price = sample(350000:625000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
                    LotSize = sample(5000:45000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
                    SqFt = sample(18000:32000, 200, replace=TRUE), 
                    Bedroom = sample(3:5, 200, replace=TRUE), 
                    HomeAge = rnorm(200, mean=15, sd=5), 
                    CountryCode = sample(300:305, 200, replace=TRUE))

Country<-unique(House$CountryCode)
n=length(Country)
  for (i in 1:length(Country)) {
  Country[i]->Testing
    allModels = lapply(Country,function(x){
  lm(Price~Bedroom, data=House[House$CountryCode==Testing,])})}
```

It is running the model six times for the last instance of "Testing" or 305 in this case.

Comment: Why not : `integrated_model <- model_50006<-lm(HomePrice ~ LotSize + SqFt + Bedroom + HomeAge + factor(ZipCode), 
    data=House)`

Comment: I updated the question with a small change; instead of zip code, changed it to reflect country. The issue I am running across is that because of the fx rate, a value like price is not a true continuous variable. 300,000 euros =! 300,000 USD and ideally, would want to have the same model run for each different country. It comes down to grouping to "like terms" which in my case, is country. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work how I wanted via the below code;

```
Country<-unique(House$CountryCode)
CountryCodeModel <- list()
for (i in 1:length(Country)) {
  Model<-lm(Price~LotSize+SqFt+Bedroom+HomeAge, data=House[House$CountryCode==Country[i],])
  CountryCodeModel[[i]] <- summary(Model)}
names(CountryCodeModel) = Country
```